# How do I write to an SD Card using SPI for the PSoC 5LP chip?

Tags: c, embedded, sd-card, spi

How do I write to an SD Card using SPI with DMA available for the [PSoC 5LP (32-bit Cortex-M3)](http://www.cypress.com/products/psoc-5lp) chip?

I currently have a DMA and SPI tx/rx pair working, but for a different purpose so if the actual transmission is not an issue, I just don't know how to interact with the SDcard.

The [datasheet for the PSoC 5LP is here](http://www.cypress.com/file/45906/download).

Basic Info:

I am using the DMA in simple mode and the DMA TD chain is setup for:
8 bit width, 4 Byte bursts
auto complete the full TD (only needs initial HW request)
Loop back to beginning of initial TD when done and wait for HW request

The SPI Master is initialized in a gui, I have it set using a 16Mhz clock, 8 bit tx/rx transfers with a 4 Byte tx/rx buffer.  interrupts are set on rx FIFO full, connected to them is an rx DMA.

The pointers for the SDcard SPI rx/tx are SPIM_RX_PTR and SPIM_TX_PTR respectively.  The DMA transfers to and from them.  The Arrays that I am transferring from and to are SDcardout and SDcardin.

Comment: This is too broad because: No System on Chip (SoC) is specified; and each SoC may already have library capabilities to doing this.  Also, which registers are we writing to?  Each SoC has different channels for their SPI communication bus. Also, are we talking SPI 5W or "regular" SPI ?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for the help
If more is needed I can post my actual code when I get to my other computer, although I don't know how much help itll be.

Comment: I don't think that any of the information George has requested is at all necessary to answer the question.  Given a working SPI driver, the problem is entirely abstracted away from any particular processor or DMA controller.  The implementation of such a driver may have an impact on performance, but that is not the question.

Comment: @clifford The reason I ask for it is that some SoCs have drivers for their SPI stuff; and it's invoked a certain way. Since the OP needs this for the psoc-5lp, making sure an answer is compatible with their SPI driver (if they have one) is important to be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker  I do have an SPI driver on my device, I can access it either via DMA or from the software.  It is flexible (bit width/buffer lengths)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker  : I thought it clear from the question that he had a working SPI driver, and that any adaptation required to suit SD card comms would probably be trivial (because SPI is very simple), and hardly the biggest issue in accessing the card.

Comment: @Clifford The question is never just for the OP; but for anyone who searches for this problem and comes across this question. The OP may have a working SPI driver implementation via that chip; but what about the next person? That's why we want questions and answers to show some working code; because code is precise and immediately shows whether the question / answer is what the searcher needs.

Comment: @Clifford This XKCD comic famously represents the issue: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : The question is simply much broader than the OP perhaps understood, and clearly broader than you understand, as you attempt to narrow it to an entirely different question. Perhaps when you post an answer it will be possible to understand how you appear to be interpreting this question so differently from me

Comment: @Clifford If the question is too broad; perhaps you should vote to close and explain why it's too broad so the OP can narrow it down?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker :  ... because it is *not* too broad.  Being broader than anticipated, is not the same as being *too* broad.  SO would be far less interesting, and programming a rather trivial art if every question could be answered in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having SPI communication will only get you the lowest command/block level access to the card;  you will need a file system.  SD cards come pre-formatted as FAT32, so a FAT file-system will provide the greatest comparability, is not the greatest reliability (corruption is likely if write is interrupted by power loss or reset for example).  It also has the advantage of being relatively simple to implement and requires few resources.

There are several commercial and open-source FAT filesystems libraries available.  I suggest that you look at [ELM FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) or [ELM Petit FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_p.html) both have permissive licences and are well documented.  In each case you simply need to implement the disk I/O stubs to map them to your SPI driver.  There are plenty of examples, documentation and application notes on the site to help you. You can start with an SPI SD implementation example for another target and adapt it to your driver (or adapt your driver perhaps).  Other FAT filesystem libraries are broadly similar to this and require I/O layer implementation.

The diskio layer of ELM FatFs is not media specific, so you in fact need an additional MMC/SD layer between that and the SPI driver.  It is unlikely that you will find an example for your specific target, but it is possible to work from examples for other targets since MMC/SD over SPI itself is not target specific, the hardware dependencies come only at the SPI level and the GPIO implementation for the card-detect and write-protect (optional) signals.  There are several examples for various ARM targets [here](http://siwawi.bauing.uni-kl.de/avr_projects/arm_projects/arm_memcards/), a project for PSoC support [here](https://github.com/hackingchips/PSoCFatFs) (apparently a work-in-progress at time of writing).

Comment: This is a great starting point for an answer; unfortunately the complaint at we have about embedded development carries over to this answer as well; simply linking someone to documentation and saying "this is well documented" is not good enough for Stack Overflow. We want answers that actually solve the problem specified without having to look at external sites or do extra work.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker :  The documentation I refer to is the documentation for the library, not an answer to the question.  This is not a "link only" answer.  The answer to the question is that you need a filesystem.  Supporting that answer, I suggest that one uses a library rather then attempting to implement it from scratch.  Suggestion of a specific library was just helpful - the answer would stand without that..  It is apparent from the question that scarslo9 is not aware of the need for a filesystem.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : What is *"the complaint at we have about embedded development"*?  I have no idea what that refers to in the context your you comment?  What complaint?  Whose complaining? Who are "we"?

Comment: I've spent a lot of time recently doing embedded development; and your answer is representative of answers I've seen where there is some useful information, but nothing that actually solves the user's problem.  That's a common refrain in embedded development it isn't helpful for new users.  An answer (in the context of what we want answers to be on Stack Overflow) would include sample code to actually solve the User's problem using the library you link to.

Comment: The link is helpful in showing me how little I knew and giving me a place to start.. before I was using a library to do it in software, but I didn't realize how much was going on behind the scenes.. I take it theres more to it than just some simple commands to send out like write/read and where to write/read from?...  It would be helpful to have something more to go on though.. there has to be an example out there of this using DMA, I can port it as long as it has the bytes to be sent.  Idk if its that simple or not though.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : The problem is perhaps that in embedded systems, the world is not exclusively x86 and not either Windows, OSX or Linux.  There are instead, hundreds of possible processors, many architectures, both COTS and custom board designs, and any number of OS's and kernels or no OS at all. and when a question is asked, it is likely that the person answering has never used the precise platform the OP is asking about - that is no how embedded system development works.  Answeres are therefore often necessarily more abstract and less direct.

Comment: @scarlso9 : Any examples I have are for STM32 and partially written in C++.  I have added information that may help.  Note that the SPI implementation (DMA, byte-by-byte or bit-banged) will affect performance not function;  you might worry about that once you have it fundamentally working.  At its lower level you need to be able to read and write bytes, and control the CS (some operations require data to be clocked with CS deselected).

Comment: @scarlso9 : I found this:  https://github.com/hackingchips/PSoCFatFs  but PSoC 5LP support appears to be a work-in-progress.

Comment: @Clifford Doesn't mean we can't change that. Some code is better than none at all.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : Then we must agree to differ.  An answer to the kind you seem to think is necessary is not one I can give in any way I think would be useful, and to not answer at all would help even less.  When a better answer is posted I will gladly concede - I look forward to yours.  Your lamenting of the quality of answers on [embedded] is somewhat galling having posted 693 answers and never having previously encountered you.

Comment: @Clifford Just started embedded development a few months ago; It's surprising how hard it is to get embedded engineers to share code. Not used to it; and it's vastly different from other programming communities I've been a part of.

Comment: @Clifford I appreciate your answer, you were correct, and I will gladly accept it as answered.  If you could answer one last question for me, I would be very grateful.  In your link is a link to http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html it references commands, I have been reading all elm-chan stuff, but I cannot find anything about what bits I'm to send for the commands (CMD0,CMD1,etc).  I've glanced over documents at sdcard.org (and everywhere else I can find) but have found nothing.  ideally something that lays out the bits for the whole command frame commands and potential responses.

Comment: @scarlso9 : The "simplified" SD card physical layer specification can be found at https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/index.html - the section on *SPI mode* applies.  In my case I did not need that information, I simply adapted the existing examples.  Only a small subset of all possible commands is in fact necessary.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for all your help, I see what you are referring to, I missed it the first time through but I found it now thanks to your help.  I think I have enough to go on now and know what I am up against.

Answer (score 0):

I have done work on exactly this problem.

I found that the existing SPI module provided with the PSoC 5 components library is not ideally suited to bulk transfers to / from an SD card. As far as I could tell, it was necessary to clear SPI module flags in software on each byte transfer, rendering DMA much less useful. I think one solution is to use two TDs (Transfer descriptors) - one to perform the data transfer and a second to clear the RX flag after the first TD has completed - anyway, that's off topic.

I also found that the emFile component supplied in the components library is limited in its capabilities. I couldn't see any way to attach DMA, and even if I could, its clock speed appeared to be very poor. On top of this, emFile requires compile-time selection of FAT16 or FAT32, limiting your design to one or another filesystem only.

As I didn't like the idea of a more complicated DMA setup, I decided to design my own SPI component hardware in the UDB editor. The project containing the component can be found at: https://github.com/PolyVinalDistillate/NSDSPI

This incorporates the excellent FatFS library mentioned above (thanks ChaN), which takes care of FAT12, FAT16 and FAT32 formatted cards. As stated, without the filesystem layer, you will only be accessing raw data blocks of 512 bytes each. With FatFS, you get analogues of fopen(), fclose(), etc.

If you look at my component in PSoC Creator, you'll see it's actually composed of 2 components: One is the specialised UDB component implementing the main SPI logic, the other is a schematic connecting my UDB component to DMA and some control logic. This second component also has the API files containing my hardware-specific code and is the component to drop into your TopDesign schematic.

FatFS is included as a precompiled library, and LowLevelFilesys.h in the API folder provides access to all the file functions.

This component was designed with bulk-reads in mind and the API does the following for read:

- Sets up a DMA TD of the required data length and tells my SPI component how many bytes will be transferred.
- Triggers the transfer, causing my SPI component to send 0xFF automatically (no need to write 0xFF to the SPI for every byte received), while copying each received byte into the receive buffer via DMA.

Writing the card is performed in a more typical fashion, with the DMA simply sending data to the SPI module after preparing the SD card for it.

If you run my project on your PSoC system, it will perform a read / write test on the SD card, depositing a file reporting the specs:

```
Testing Speed
Writing 16000 bytes to file, non-DMA
Took 94 ms
Rate 1361 kbps

Reading 16000 bytes to file, non-DMA
Took 50 ms
Verifying... All Good! :D
Rate 2560 kbps

Writing 16000 bytes to file, DMA
Took 17 ms
Rate 7529 kbps

Reading 16000 bytes to file, DMA
Took 12 ms
Verifying... All Good! :D
Rate 10666 kbps
```

Some SD cards give better results, some give worse. I believe this is down to the SD card itself (e.g. class, usage, age of tech, etc).